# macOS - User can perform admin tasks but cannot sudo

Tags: catalina, administrator, sudo

- MacOS Catalina 10.15.3 Centrify 5.5.2-702
- UserA is a "Mobile" (AD
  Authenticated) user showing as "Admin" in Users & Groups
- UserA is shown as a member of the local "admin" group when running "groups x" or "id"
- UserA can perform admin tasks in the GUI (such as installing software,
  unlocking System Preferences etc)
- UserA **cannot** sudo on a particular MacX "xxx is not in the
  sudoers file. This incident will be reported."
- UserA **can** sudo on other Macs(Y,Z,...)
- Logs show Centrify PAM is successful. Other (local) users can sudo
  (no issue with the sudo file)

I'm at a loss why this is happening - and have spent hours troubleshooting this to no avail. Any help where to look next would be incredibly helpful!

Comment: To use `sudo` that user must be in the `sudoers` file or in a group that is in the `sudoers` file.  I would check the groups first - make sure that user is in the appropriate group (should be wheel)

Comment: @Allan the user is reported as a member of admin group 80 (and I can run GUI admin commands such as unlocking user preferences etc).  My current thinking is that its part of the pam chain with Centrify or something similar that is not reporting a membership of the admin group in time.

Comment: @klanomath is correct, I mix up FreeBSD and macOS from time to time.  As for Centrify, it’s not a matter of “in time” because you’ve logged in, you’re in the group.

Comment: @klanomath - that file has the expected 6(ish) lines referencing centrify (and I’ve checked this against another Mac running the same version of Mac OS and Centrify), these are identical.

Comment: Since I’ve posted - I’ve also cleared my users Cache (~/Library/Cache), Preferences (~/Library/Preferences), and cleared by local opendirectory profile.  No change

Comment: I’ve been able to login to another Mac on the network and sudo, and other users can also sudo on their machines.

Comment: @Buzbe "I’ve been able to login to another Mac on the network" means "I=User**A** is a "Mobile" (AD Authenticated) user showing as "Admin" in Users & Groups"? Or with other words: User**A** can't use sudo on one particular Mac but on all other Macs **and** User**B** (also admin) **can** use sudo on this particular Mac?

Comment: My user is showing as Mobile and Admin on this Mac - and cannot sudo.  On other macs, I have sudo rights. 

Have not tried another admin (and mobile user) on this Mac yet.

Comment: @Klanomath - yep correct.  Still no luck on my side though.  Very challenging issue!

Comment: @Buzbe Did you already try to login with User**B** (Mobile and Admin) on Mac**X** and execute `sudo ...`?

Comment: Is your user using a non-default terminal client? I noticed after upgrading to Catalina that I could sudo in Terminal.app but not iterm2. After granting iTerm2 full disk access I was able to sudo again

Comment: I got the same problem. Mobile user, belong to Admin group. I can manage all my Mac settings and access any files, but sudo doesn't work.
Tried granting full disk permission to the iTerm and Term.app – didn't help.